# Connecting to already running Flask Server on Ubuntu VM after re-connection using ssh

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, flask

I have started a flask server on a ubuntu vm machine,which I connect thru using SSH. Once the Server is started, I logged out from ssh and re-connect again to the server using ssh but this time the server is found running but doesn't take any http calls like get/post etc. I'm running the server using '&' so that the process runs in background and after logout/disown doesn't stop the server.